# How can I edit the title of saved/starred places in Google Maps Android?

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps Android 5.10 you can save a place by clicking and starring the place. However, the name of the saved place is automatically generated by Maps, and can't be edited.

Is there a good way to edit that title, to show the correct/actual name of that place for example?

Googling I only found a solution involving editing the starred place in Google Bookmarks webapps. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update 11 Jan 2016*
In latest Google Maps Android (version 9.18.2 2015) there is now an "Add Label" feature/command available when you view a saved/starred place. See [Give a place a private label](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/6257830?hl=en) for detailed instructions.

*Old workaround (no longer necessary)*
After starring a place in Google Maps Android, you can open [Google Bookmarks webapps](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/) to display your bookmarks. Sort by date to show your latest bookmark and clicking on the `Edit` button allows you to edit that place bookmark title. The new title would display in `My Places` (now shown as `Your Places`) on Google Maps Android. Not an ideal solution, but a workaround involving additional webapps.

*Update 13 July 2015*
Unfortunately latest Google Maps Android (version 9.11.0 2015) doesn't show the place bookmark titles that you have edited in Google Bookmarks webapps.

*References*:

- Google Maps Support - [Google Maps Mobile - Give a place a private label](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/6257830?hl=en)
- Arstechnica - [Google Maps for Android finally adds custom names for places](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/07/google-maps-for-android-finally-adds-custom-names-for-places/) - 22 July 2015
- Android Forum - [Google Maps - Label Starred Locations?](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/61743-google-maps-label-starred-locations.html) - 9 April 2010 - provides three workarounds: #9 add suffix "(Title)" to address in Google Maps webapps before starring (not editing on Android); #11 use Google Bookmarks to edit title (solution I chose above); #14 add to contacts and edit contacts names (will search each time use the address in contacts).
- Google Mobile Android Forum - [Why can't I edit the name of a "Starred" place on google maps?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=4808f7d8ba446f75&hl=en) - 1 June 2011 - mentioned bookmark & contacts solutions above, also registering an address as a business place, then can edit the title.

Comment: A bit cumbersome but inevitable. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to edit `My Places` to `Your Places` as it shows in latest Google Maps Android. But I didn't see the edit to saved places title I did in Google Bookmarks webapps  showing there. I'll wait a while and see. Or can someone else confirm this workaround is still working?

Comment: @Benjamin  there is now "add label" feature on Google Maps Android. Finally. :-)